# Correlation and heteroscedasticity

Tags: statistics, correlation, data-analysis

I'm studying a dataset and observed a positive correlation between two variables, but when I plot them, it seems that they are heteroscedastics, what conclusions can I get from it ? (Can I really assume that the positive correlation is real ?)

Thanks, 
L.L.

Answer (score 1):

Your description is very vague. In the simplest case, suppose you have 10 observations $X_1, \dots, X_{10}$ and 10 observations $Y_1, \dots, Y_{10}$
and you want to find the correlation between them.

If the sample variances
$S_x^2$ and $X_y^2$ are very different, that does not interfere with
computing or interpreting a correlation. For example if the $X$-values
are $X = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)$ and the $Y$-values are
$Y = (100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000),$ then the variances
are quite different, but the correlation is $r = 1,$ reflecting the
obvious linear relationship between the $X$'s and the $Y$'s.

If you had something more complicated in mind, please explain it in
more detail.

*Addendum:* The correlation $r$ has no units, and so is not influenced
by the scale of either of the two variables. Changing units of $X$ from
meters to cm would increase the numerical SD by 100, but would not change the
correlation $r$ with another variable $Y$ (perhaps measured in kg).